# Counting frequency of characters in a line from a .txt file

Tags: c#

I have a C# task to do and I am stuck on part of the coding. I am using StreamReader to read a .txt file which contains group exam grade data (e.g. ADCBCBBBADEBCCBADBAACDCCBEDCBACCFEABBCBBBCCEAABCBB), I need the code to work out how many A's, B's etc there are inside each set of data, I thought about using some form of count++ code but each attempt just throws errors.

I want it to print onto console the number of A's in that line of the .txt file.

I hope that makes sense, I understand how to do the rest but I just needed a hand on this section.

Comment: What did you try already? What did it do? How was that different from what you wanted? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Show us what you've tried ...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `System.Linq`, eg...

```
string myString = "ADCBCBBBADEBCCBADBAACDCCBEDCBACCFEABBCBBBCCEAABCBB";
int countOfAs = myString.Count(x => x == 'A');
//Result: 9
```

Comment: How would I do that with StreamReader so that if the .txt file is changed it will still work.

Comment: `StreamReader.ReadLine()` returns a string value, for example `string myString = StreamReader.ReadLine()` which would replace the `string myString ...` line from the answer.